# How can I add a custom class to the AmChart legend?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to wrap a html tag around the labels in the legend. I looked through the documentation for `AmLegend()`, and I didn't find anything immediately obvious. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

the legend comes already with "amChartsLegend" but if you prefer your own classNames you can access it within the created chart instance "legendDiv"

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart({...});
chart.legendDiv.classList.add('your-classname');
```

i hope that helped :)

**UPDATE**

Ensure the [browser supports the "classList"](https://caniuse.com/#search=classList) feature otherwise you need to add a [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/) for that.

Here is a one-liner to check the support to add the polyfill or not.

`("classList" in document.createElement("_"))`

Comment: Not working please can you give me little more detail

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: it's only available if you've a legend defined in your chart instance. Besides of that ensure your browser supports "classList". I've updated my answer, see below.